# best way to handle subscriptions with a licence?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, subscription, licensing

I have a product with 3 packs: 
- 14-days trial (user should not have to enter paypal details)
- monthly
- yearly

We used WooCommerce with "WooCommerce Subscriptions" and "WooCommerce Software License". 
And we want to use PayPal.

There was also a problem with recurring payments and PayPal Plus so let's assume we use PayPal Standard which is supported by WooComemrce and WooCommerce Subscriptions.

The problem is the "14-days trial" logic:

1. If I create a subscription with a 14-day free trial then it would charge the user after those 14 days because it's only a delay.
2. If I put the price to $0 then the user could renew it for $0
3. I can create a simple product and only use the licence manager and creating a licence which expires after 14 days. But then the user will not be able renew it. He would have to go to the page again and order the correct subscription.

Does anyone has some experience with subscriptions, free trial and licences?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about specific plugins are off-topic for WPSE. These are best handled through the plugin's support channels.

Comment: Oh, OK. sorry. Will move my question to the woocommerce forums